# Spring form unable to submit

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc

What is wrong with my Spring Form?

```
<form:form id="projectEdit" action="../projects/projectEditor.do" method="POST" modelAttribute="wrapper">
    <c:forEach var="projectBean" items="${ projectList }" varStatus="i">
        <tr>
           <td>
              ${ projectBean.code }
              <form:hidden path="projectBeanList[${i.index}].id"/>
              <form:hidden path="projectBeanList[${i.index}].code"/>
           </td>
           <td>
              ${ projectBean.name }
              <form:hidden path="projectBeanList[${i.index}].name"/>
           </td>

    </c:forEach>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
        <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save
    </button>
</form:form>
```

my form doesn't submit and no errors too. I don't know what is wrong?

Comment: Please show generated HTML of form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I don't know why but the form should be outside the table.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with

```
projectBeanList[${i.index}].*
```

Where did you define 'projectBeanList' variable?